# subprocess popen is returning blanck output

Tags: python, scripting, grep, subprocess, popen

On trying to run the grep for the output of previous command using popen returning blank without any error

```
proc1cmd = "grep " + fetchname1
   p1 = subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'get', 'abr', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   p2 = subprocess.Popen(proc1cmd, shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   p1.stdout.close() 
   stdout_list = p2.communicate()[0]
   stdout_list = stdout_list.decode()
   print(p2.stdout)
   print(p2.communicate())
```

output i got:

```
<_io.BufferedReader name=7>
   (b'', b'')
```

Comment: You don't need to pipe to `grep` – just filter the `kubectl` output list with Python...

Comment: @AKX: Thanks for the suggestion. 
I really couldn't reach complete comment from you. 

here in my case, i have list of abr in our environment, i just need to get a result on the status of the one which is loaded in 'fetchname1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to concoct a pipeline of kubectl + grep here.

```
kubectl_output = subprocess.check_output(
    ["kubectl", "get", "abr", "-A"], encoding="utf-8"
)
matching_lines = [
    line for line in kubectl_output.splitlines() if fetchname1 in line
]
print(matching_lines)
```